# Neural Network XOR with numpy not converging

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have trained a Neural Net to solve the XOR problem. The problem with my network is that it is not converging. I am using Andrew Ng's methods and notations as taught in the DeepLearning.ai course.

Here's the code :

```
import numpy as np
from __future__ import print_function

X = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
Y = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0]])
np.random.seed(1)
W1 = np.random.randn(3, 2) * 0.0001
b1 = np.ones((3, 1))
W2 = np.random.randn(1, 3) * 0.0001
b2 = np.ones((1, 1))
```

The next part for the Backpropagation:

```
learning_rate = 0.01
m = 4
for iteration in range(100000):

    # forward propagation
    # layer1
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X.T) + b1
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1)
    # layer2
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)

    # backpropagation

    dZ2 = Y - A2
    dW2 = (1 / m) * np.dot(dZ2, A1.T)
    db2 = (1 / m) * np.sum(dZ2, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    dZ1 = np.dot(dW2.T, dZ2) * sigmoid_gradient(Z1)
    dW1 = (1 / m) * np.dot(dZ1, X)
    db1 = (1 / m) * np.sum(dZ1, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    # checking if shapes are correctly preserved

    assert (dZ2.shape == Z2.shape)
    assert (dW2.shape == W2.shape)
    assert (db2.shape == b2.shape)
    assert (dZ1.shape == Z1.shape)
    assert (dW1.shape == W1.shape)
    assert (db1.shape == b1.shape)

    # update parameters

    W1 = W1 + learning_rate * dW1
    W2 = W2 + learning_rate * dW2
    b1 = b1 + learning_rate * db1
    b2 = b2 + learning_rate * db2

    # print every 10k
    if (iteration % 10000 == 0):
        print(A2)
```

Comment: XOR is quite interesting problem to try and solve as it has 2 solutions in 2D (and more in 3D, think about it). Given the "right" weights/biases and learning rate it is possible to get stuck between these 2 (or more..)  solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a couple of mistakes in your code. For example, in computing the `W2`.

```
...
dZ2 = Y - A2
dW2 = (1 / m) * np.dot(dZ2, A1.T)
...
W2 = W2 + learning_rate * dW2
```

We want to calculate the derivative of `Cost` with respect to `W2` using the chain rule.

[image: Formula_1]

We can write the derivatives as follows:

[image: Formula_2]

You haven't implemented the middle part which computes the derivative of the `Z2`.

You can check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8&t=344s) video, it explains the math part of backpropagation. Moreover, you can check out [this](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) simple implementation of the neural network.